# The equivalent of jquery $.when in Python Tornado

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, tornado

In jQuery `$.when(promise1, promise2...)` is used as a **master promise** to represent the overall status of its children promises. We can then attach `.done(callback)` to the `$.when` promise so that when ALL `promise1, promise2...` finish the `callback` will be executed.

In Python (Tornado), the `Future` acts similar to the promise in javascript, and the `fetch()` in `AsyncHTTPClient` returns a Future.

In the following code I have a list of futures

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

httpclient = AsyncHTTPClient()
futures = [
    httpclient.fetch("http://google.com")
    httpclient.fetch("http://example.com")
    httpclient.fetch("http://example.org")
]

def all_futures_done_callback():
    ...
```

How do I execute the `all_futures_done_callback` when all futures finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you'll need to build this functionality yourself.  This is untested, but something like this seems like it should work:

```
class FutureCollection(Future):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FutureCollection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._waiting_for = []

    def _check_all_done_and_resolve(self, future):
        if all(f.done() for f in self._waiting_for):
            # Maybe check for exceptions a. la.
            # http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/concurrent.html#chain_future
            self.set_result(None)  # Not sure what the result should be.

    def add_future(self, future):
        self._waiting_for.append(future)
        future.add_done_callback(self._check_all_done_and_resolve)

    @property
    def futures(self):
        # Read-only access to the futures that have been added.
        return iter(self._waiting_for)
```

Comment: Ben's answer is concise but yours are more extensible, so I accepted your answer. Thanks both of you!

Comment: @MKYung -- To be fair, I've never used tornado before ;-).  I've just gotten a little familiar with promises in my JS experience recently so I thought I'd give it a try in a different language.

Answer (score 2):

In a coroutine it's easy to wait for multiple futures; just yield them all as a list:

```
@gen.coroutine
def f():
    futures = [
        httpclient.fetch("http://google.com")
        httpclient.fetch("http://example.com")
        httpclient.fetch("http://example.org")
    ]
    responses = yield futures
```

To do this with callbacks instead of coroutines you'll need something like mgilson's answer.